# MySQL workbench fonts are very small on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, fonts, mysql-workbench

MySQL left sidebar fonts are very small on my computer which is having (1920 x 1080) and running on windows 10 pro. I tried to change the font size by changing the scaling, resolutions and MySQL compatibility but nothing changes.

Comment: This is more than likely caused by **DPI awareness** introduced into Windows 10

Comment: how can I fix this?

Comment: Try this: Find the .EXE fie for the app. Right-click on it and select “properties”. Click on “compatibility”. Under “settings”, check the box for “Disable Display Scaling for high DPI settings”.

Comment: I have only Disable full-screen optimisation and checked it, but not working